# where's the error and why this program is wrong?

Tags: c++, function, class, object, overloading

I'm doing an exercise for homework where i have to create a class for a fraction , but when i was coding i got in trouble with the overloading of the operator << ,and i don't understand where's the error because when the program reads the input the two numbers(numerator,denominator) are saved correctly, but when i try to print in output the fraction it gives me a random number; why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Frazione{
    private:
        int num;
        int den;
    public:

        Frazione operator+(Frazione f2){
            Frazione risultato;
            risultato.den=MCM(f2.den);
            risultato.num=(num*(risultato.den/den))+(f2.num*(risultato.den/f2.den));
            return risultato;
        }

        int MCM(int a){
            int min;
            int k;
            if(den>a){
                min=a;
            }
            else{
                min=den;
            }
            for(int i=min;!(den%i==0 && a%min==0);i+=min){
                k=i;
            }
            return k;
        }

        void setn(int a){
            num=a;
        }

        void setd(int a){
            den=a;
        }

        int getn(){
            return num;
        }

        int getd(){
            return den;
        }

};

        istream& operator>>(istream& in,Frazione f){
            int n,d;
            cout<<"Dimmi il numeratore"<<endl;
            in>>n;
            cout<<"Dimmi il denominatore"<<endl;
            in>>d;
            f.setn(n);
            f.setd(d);
            return in;
        }

        ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,Frazione& f){
            out<<f.getn();
            out<<"/";
            out<<f.getd();
            return out;
        }

int main(){
Frazione f1,f2,f3;
    cin>>f1;
    cout<<f1;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Currently don't pay attention to funciont MCM and operator+ because they are function that i have to implement then i'll solve this plobem.

Comment: Your `operator >>` takes `Frazione` parameter *by value*, not *by reference*. You are reading input into a copy and that copy is discarded once function finishes

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thank you ,so with the overloading of operator >> i always have to use by reference

Comment: on the other hand your `operator<<` does take `Frazzione` as non-const reference, when in fact it does not modify it. The method `getd` should be declared as  `const`

Comment: @ric When it's used to input data from stream, then (probably) yes, it should be always by reference. At least I can't think of any good example where it shouldn't be used like that.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed the reference of the second parameter here:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in,Frazione &f)
```

The parameter f is only accessible by reference.